# Can jQuery give me a list of children excluding certain sub-tags by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an editor which first generates forms (C++ code) then which connects itself to various final HTML widgets (JavaScript code) to support many advance features implemented using jQuery.

At this time, the forms that the editor connect to are well behaved and one cannot include another. However, I have one case where that would be practical. So...

There a simplified version of the generated HTML:

```
<div id="form1" class="snap-editor">
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
    ...
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
</div>

<div id="form2" class="snap-editor">
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
    ...
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
</div>
```

In this case I can very easily generate a list of JavaScript objects representing each form. I use two level queries, something like this:

```
forms = jQuery(".snap-editor");
for(i = 0; i < forms.length; ++i)
{
  widgets = forms[i].find(".snap-widget");
  for(j = 0; j < widgets.length; ++j)
  {
    w = widgets[j];
    ... // do stuff on the 'w' widget
  }
}
```

Now, I'm wondering whether there would be a way to use a call similar to `forms.find(".snap-widget")` but that would also exclude any `'.snap-editor'` sub-div tags and their children?

There would be the new type of HTML I would use where we can see that form2 is inside form1:

```
<div id="form1" class="snap-editor">
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
    ...
  <div class="snap-widget">...</div>

  <!-- second form is now a sub-form in the tree -->
  <div id="form2" class="snap-editor">
    <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
    <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
    <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
      ...
    <div class="snap-widget">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I apply the previous algorithm to this tree, I get the widget of form1 and form2 when setting up form1...

**WARNING** Another important note, the examples here show the snap-widget div tags as direct children, however, in a real form, that is not the case, so using `jQuery(...).children()` is not an option, at least not by itself.

For those who have to to decipher such, there a more complete (as in real) form with a first/last name, address, terms and conditions...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div class="body">
  <div session="6a1cf46e/922188938" class="editor-form" form_name="user_settings" id="content">
    <a class="settings-save-button" href="#">Save Changes</a>
    <a class="settings-cancel-button right-aligned" href="https://csnap.m2osw.com/user/1">Cancel</a>
    <div class="clear-both"/>
    <div class="settings editing">
      <div class="required-fields"><span class="required">*</span> Required fields</div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Identity</legend>
        <div class="logo-block">
          <div class="snap-editor editable image-box picture drop immediate" field_type="image-box" field_name="picture">
            <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
              <div class="snap-editor-background-content">Drag &amp; Drop<br/>Your Photo<br/>Here</div>
            </div>
            <div max-sizes="2048x2048" title="Tooltip" class="editor-content image no-toolbar" min-sizes="64x64" name="picture" resize-sizes="150x150" tabindex="11">
              <img width="113" height="150" style="top: 0px; left: 18.5px; position: relative;" filename="Antikythera_model_front_panel_Mogi_Vicentini_2007-389x518.jpg" src="/user/1/photo.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-help image-box-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
          </div>
          <div class="settings-title">Photo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-block">
          <div class="settings-title">
            <label for="first_name" class="first_name">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <label for="last_name" class="last_name">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="clear-left"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit first_name immediate auto-focus" field_type="line-edit" field_name="first_name">
              <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
                <div class="snap-editor-background-content">first name</div>
              </div>
              <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="128" minlength="1" name="first_name" tabindex="6">Halk</div>
              <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit last_name immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="last_name">
              <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
                <div class="snap-editor-background-content">last name</div>
              </div>
              <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="128" minlength="1" name="last_name" tabindex="7">First</div>
              <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-block clear-left">
          <div class="settings-title">
            <label for="main_phone" class="main_phone">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <label for="other_phone" class="other_phone">Other Phone</label>
            <div class="clear-left"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit main_phone immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="main_phone">
              <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
                <div class="snap-editor-background-content">business phone</div>
              </div>
              <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="32" minlength="7" name="main_phone" tabindex="8">916 220 6482</div>
              <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit other_phone immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="other_phone">
              <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
                <div class="snap-editor-background-content">cell, home, or fax</div>
              </div>
              <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="32" minlength="0" name="other_phone" tabindex="9"/>
              <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-block clear-left">
          <div class="snap-editor editable checkmark read_terms_n_conditions immediate" field_type="checkmark" field_name="read_terms_n_conditions">
            <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" name="read_terms_n_conditions" tabindex="10"><div class="checkmark-flag"><div class="flag-box"/><div class="checkmark-area checked"/></div>I accept the <a target="_blank" href="/terms-and-conditions">Finball Inc. Terms and Conditions</a>.<span class="required">*</span></div>
            <div class="editor-help checkmark-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Address</legend>
        <div class="editor-block">
          <label for="address1" class="settings-title">Address</label>
          <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit address1 immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="address1">
            <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
              <div class="snap-editor-background-content">address line 1</div>
            </div>
            <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="250" minlength="0" name="address1" tabindex="12"/>
            <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
          </div>
          <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit address2 immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="address2">
            <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
              <div class="snap-editor-background-content">address line 2</div>
            </div>
            <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="250" minlength="0" name="address2" tabindex="13"/>
            <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-block">
          <div class="settings-title">
            <label for="city" class="city">City</label>
            <label for="state" class="state">State</label>
            <label for="zip" class="zip">Zip</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clear-left">
            <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit city immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="city">
              <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
                <div class="snap-editor-background-content">city</div>
              </div>
              <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="128" minlength="0" name="city" tabindex="14"/>
              <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit state immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="state">
              <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
                <div class="snap-editor-background-content">state</div>
              </div>
              <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="128" minlength="0" name="state" tabindex="15"/>
              <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-editor editable line-edit zip immediate" field_type="line-edit" field_name="zip">
              <div class="snap-editor-background zordered">
                <div class="snap-editor-background-content">zip</div>
              </div>
              <div title="Tooltip" class="editor-content no-toolbar" maxlength="32" minlength="0" name="zip" tabindex="16"/>
              <div class="editor-help line-edit-help" style="display: none;">Help</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well not having the real markup makes it hard to answer since the above is answered with one character `>`

Comment: This may be the reason why the HTML spec doesn't allow nested `form` tags.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez, yeah... one of the limitations of HTML / XML in general. Although I can do it, I'm wondering whether there is a way to do it without writing 100 lines of code... and for it to remain fast too.

Comment: @epascarello The exact markup is quite complicated. I included a sample though... just in case you had an idea (this is a single form, but imagine the second form appearing somewhere in there and looking pretty similar.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the not selector to filter descendants:

```
var widgets = jQuery(forms[i]).find(".snap-widget").not(jQuery(forms[i]).find(".snap-editor .snap-widget"));
```

The find will only be looking at descendents of the selected snap-editor, but not the selected snap-editor itself. So any snap-widgets that are descendents of the selected snap-editor will be selected - As long as they are not children of a snap-editor that is also a child of the selected element.

http://jsfiddle.net/2w4voug4/3/

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: That would be `:not(.snap-form)` since when I search for the widgets I do not want to go through the sub-"snap-form" *tags*. But I don't think I can use the `:not()` in this case.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a bit more specific. This should select all snap-widgets that are not inside another snap-editor inside your outer snap-editor.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, also I did not have much luck with the `:not()` operator before and it did not work in this case either. I also tried the `.not()` function filter and it didn't work either. The reason, I'm pretty sure, is that the `not` is applied **after** it already made the selection and then it checks whether the children of the select match that selector... In my case I would have to test the parent instead.

Comment: You're right. I was under the impression that `:not` and `.not()` were the same thing. I've changed the answer and included a link to the JSFiddle I was messing around in.

Comment: Yes! I just found how to do that on my own too. This way it works as you get a list of all then remove a list of a few that are unwanted. I have a test and that works!

Answer (score 0):

I know you said the mark-up is not the same, but you probably will need to use the [direct child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and make a selector that is more specific than just the single class.

Solution for sample code:

```
forms[i].find("> .snap-widget")
```

Without the real code it is hard to give you a real solution.